# What is the use of label in clipboard?

Tags: android, clipboard

I am copying something to clipboard using the label "my_text". While each copy is occurring i want to retrieve the current text in clipboard belongs to "my_text" label, and append the new data.

For copy to clipboard i am using the below code

```
public static void copyToClipboard(Context context, String text){
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(text);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("my_text",text);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

But in the case of past from clipboard, i couldn't  find any method to get text belongs to label.

Comment: i need label of copied text too. but how , i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

ClipData has method [getDescription()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html#getDescription())

> Return the ClipDescription associated with this data, describing what it contains.

ClipDescription is

> Meta-data describing the contents of a ClipData.

If you use a plain text **label** for your ClipData you can use something like:

```
clip.getDescription().getLabel().toString();
```

to get it.

Hope it helps.